# Other than being a god what speciality did Rama have to lift and break Shiva dhanush?

Tags: rama

We heard that in the swayamvara of Sita. The one who can lift the dhanush(Shiva's bow) will be termed as the worthiest to take the hand of sita. Although some says that Ravana also tried his luck and could only lift the bow a bit but finally gave up. Rama was the only one who lifted it. But I want to know a thing other than being a god himself id Rama have any speciality to lift the bow ....

Answer (score 2):

I think the best Answer of your Question Should be **NO**

Without any specialty [He](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama) was able to lift the shiva bow Cause He was incarnation of lord [Vishnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu) and both of god [Vishnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu) and [Shiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiv) are same
It ain't true that only [Rama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama) Can Lift The Bow Of Shiva.
In Mythology there is a story Of Sita
In her childhood, Sita lifted the bow single handily and having seen that Janaka decided that he would give his daughter only to the man who could lift the bow.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Dhanush) is the source of Wikipedia

> King Janaka of Mithila had a daughter named [Sita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sita). In earlier part of her life, Sita while playing with her sisters had unknowingly lifted the table over which the bow had been placed; which was something no one in the kingdom could do. This incident was however observed by Janaka and he decided to make this incident as the backdrop for [Swayamvara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swayamvara).

Why Rama Lifted The [Shiva Dhanush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva_Dhanush):

- He was an Incarnation of [Lord Vishnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu)
- Sita was also an incarnation of [Maa Lakshmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakshmi) and everyone know it well that she could only be with Rama Like Lakshmi Could only be With [Lord Vishnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu)
- Both the God [Vishnu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu) and [Shiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiv) are Same there is nothing difference beetween them.

Comment: You should cite sources.